# postgresql create auxiliary list

Tags: postgresql

I have a table from which I want to delete a series of rows, but the list is variable (and hard-coded), so I wanted to define an auxiliary list.
I know I can do this

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 4, 6, 7)
```

But the question is if I can define a variable called list, like I would do in Java or Python.

```
DEFINE list (1, 4, 6, 7)
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using VALUES, eg:

```
t=# with aux_list(v) as (values (1),(4),(6),(7))
select * from generate_series(1,9,1) g where g in (select v from aux_list);
 g 
---
 1
 4
 6
 7
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Use `set` statement to set value and `current_setting()` to retrieve it:

```
set public.list to '{1,4,6,7}';

select *
from generate_series(1,10) as i
where i = any(current_setting('public.list')::int[]);
```

Notes:

Parameter name should contain the dot, for example just `list` is invalid.

I have used the synonym for `column in (<list>)` with array which allows to have the list as a single value.

`set` statement sets the variable only for session. If you want to keep it use `alter ... set ...` instead;

```
alter database my_db set public.list to '{1,4,6,7}';
```

for database or

```
alter role my_role set public.list to '{1,4,6,7}';
```

for the particular user (you should to re-login to get the effect in this case).

The alternative way is to create the view:

```
create view list(x) as values(1),(4),(6),(7);
```

and use it in this way:

```
select *
from generate_series(1,10) as i
where i in (table list);
```